# What is the elegant way to set start and end of indexing of Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to retrieve data from Pandas data frame with optional start and end index. For example, an ugly way is like this

```
def get_data(self, start=None, end=None):
   if start is None and end is not None:
      return self.data[:end]
   if start is not None and end is None:
      return self.data[start:]
   if start is not None and end is not None:
      return self.data[start:end]
```

Is there any elegant way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_data(self, start=None, end=None):
    idx = self.data.index
    start = idx[0] if start is None else start
    end = idx[-1] if end is None else end
    return self.data.loc[start:end]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It should work for location indexing. How about indexing of time series data with time range?

Comment: Great! I'll use it. Thanks!